# Cannot access moodle from another computer

Tags: moodle

I have installed moodle on my laptop. But i am unable to access it from other computers connected on the same network. However there is no problem in accessing it on my laptop. I have already gone through the solutions posted on moodle forum but none solved my issue.

Comment: Can you ping the laptop from the other machines? What web server, OS are you using? Are you using some firewalls?

Comment: @franzlorenzon ![ping result][1] I am working on Windows 7. Server is Apache. Windows Firewall is there.
[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nWrmK.jpg

Comment: So what is the error that your browser gives when you try to get the Moodle home page? Is you Apache installation reachable from the other computers?

Comment: Home page come up but when you click on login or any other link, the lick does not open.
![This page comes up when you click the link][1] [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yNpT1.png

Comment: What about the apache logs?

Comment: i don't have any knowledge about apache logs. what are they? Where would i find them?

Comment: http://windows.fyicenter.com/72_Apache_Reviewing_Apache_Server_Log_Files.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `config.php` and replace `localhost` in :

```
$CFG->wwwroot = 'http://localhost';
```

With your server's external IP.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP and used the moodle bitnami-module installer to install moodle. For me the config file I needed to edit was located at: <relative to the XAMPP installation> "\apps\moodle\htdocs\config.php"

Comment: Shouldn't the answer say "server's internal IP" instead of "server's external IP"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it from another computer on the network, you will need to set up a virtual host in Apache

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

So the domain is yourcomputer.yournetwork - something like that.

You will also need to change $CFG->wwwroot in config.php to yourcomputer.yournetwork

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using XAMPP and used the bitnami-module installer to install moodle. 
The config file needed to edit is located at:

```
relative to the XAMPP installation "\apps\moodle\htdocs\config.php"
```

From here follow the instructions of the accepted answer above. This will make moodle accessible from any computer within the LAN and also from the internet too if port forwarding on the router is enabled.